# IOC container on nested view models

Tags: wpf, mvvm, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I'm developing a WPF application trying to adhere as much as possible to MVVM patterns, including DI and IoC.
The application is structured as "ViewModel first" where the visual hierarchy contains what follows:

```
 MainView
 |-Login View
 |-Content View
   |-Content A
   |-Content B
   |-Content x
```

Each view is referenced by its VM; "MainViewModel" and "ContentViewModel" expose a property which references the child VM to control the navigation of the inner elements.
That said "Content A", "Content B" and similar items have dependencies on various services which I would like to manage through DI.

I use a UnityContainer and I register all the dependencies in the "OnStartup" but here it comes my question: as I don't want to use a ServiceLocator how can I make the "sub-viewmodels" aware of the container? I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong theory-side but I haven't found any reference online. 
Each tutorial/example I found online just register the dependencies in the container and then immediately resolve the models.

---

Comment: How are you creating the sub-viewmodels?

Comment: @mm8 the parent VM instantiate them and assign the object to the "CurrentSubVM" property to achieve the bind-ed View swap

Comment: And the parent has access to the container right? Then you could inject the children with the container.

Comment: @mm8 yes, the parent has access to the container. Do you mean pass the container via constructor DI to the children?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's how dependency injection works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a parent view model has access to the container and is responsible for creating any child view models, you could simply inject the child view models with a reference to the container when you instantiate them in the parent view model:

```
this.ChildViewModelProperty = new ChildViewModel(_container);
```

This is a typical example of constructor dependency injection.